# What does "Uncaught Error: NOT_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM OperationNotAllowed Exception 1" mean?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I encountered this error in Google Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM OperationNotAllowed Exception 1
```

I didn't find any results with Google. Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this site: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMException

Dom Exception 1 refers to `INDEX_SIZE_ERR`. For ex: If an index is negative, or larger than the allowed value; for example using splitText with an offset argument larger than the length of the string.